# Find the remainder mask between 2 masks in numpy for 2D array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, mask

Let's say I have a 2D array:

```
main = np.random.random((300, 200))
```

And I have two masks for this array:
e.g.,

```
mask1 = list((np.random.randint((100), size = 50), np.random.randint((200), size = 50)))
mask2 = list((np.random.randint((20), size = 10), np.random.randint((20), size = 10)))
```

I want to substitute the main values in the 2D array like:

```
main[mask1]=2
main[mask2]=1
```

which works great, but I also want to substitue all the indexes that are not mask 1 nor mask 2, by zero.

I thought about something like:

```
main[~mask1] & main[~mask2] = 0
```

which is leading me nowhere, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your requirement a better approach is constructing a zero filled array same shape as `main` and assign `1` and `2` using `mask1` and `mask2`

```
main = np.zeros(main.shape)
main[mask1]=2
main[mask2]=1
```